# QNetworkAccessManager: How to change post data at createRequest function

Tags: c++, qt, webview

I want to chagne or add something into post data at createRequest function, before send request.
How I could do?

Comment: You could read the QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkRequest docs. They are quite good.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the appropriate outgoingData argument.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#createRequest

> QNetworkReply * QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest & req, QIODevice * outgoingData = 0) [virtual protected]
>
> Returns a new QNetworkReply object to handle the operation op and request req. The device outgoingData is always 0 for Get and Head requests, but is the value passed to post() and put() in those operations (the QByteArray variants will pass a QBuffer object).
> The default implementation calls QNetworkCookieJar::cookiesForUrl() on the cookie jar set with setCookieJar() to obtain the cookies to be sent to the remote server.
> The returned object must be in an open state.